# Testing Library (VueJS) - Rendering multiple components in a it block

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, testing-library

Relatively new to testing so this is probably super simple:

I want to test a `checkbox` component. I got the basics down, however, how can I render multiple components inside an `it` block?

My code so far. I am stuck on the second test, where I want to render multiple items and check one. That would should return its value (or however we can test the selected checkbox).

The component itself it quite simple. It has a label and checkbox element and receives all the props you would expect.

Thank you!

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/vue';
import OBCheckbox from '../OBCheckbox.vue';

describe('OBCheckbox', () => {
    it('should be selected', async () => {
        const label = 'checkboxLabel1';
        const value = 'Testing Value';
        const { getByLabelText } = render(OBCheckbox, { props: { label, value } });

        const checkBox = getByLabelText(label);
        expect(checkBox).toBeChecked(value);
    });
    it('should return selected items value', async () => {
        // stuck here
    });
    it('should be disabled', async () => {
        const label = 'checkboxLabel1';
        const value = 'Testing Value';
        const disabled = true;
        const { getByLabelText } = render(OBCheckbox, { props: { label, value, disabled } });

        const checkBox = getByLabelText(label);
        expect(checkBox).toBeDisabled();
    });
    it('should be accessible', async () => {
        const label = 'checkboxLabel1';
        const value = 'Testing Value';
        const { getByRole } = render(OBCheckbox, { props: { label, value } });

        const checkBox = getByRole('checkbox');
        expect(checkBox).toBeChecked(value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what multiple components you are trying to render in one `it` block but if what you are trying to do is rendering multiple `OBCheckbox` in one `it` block, then probably you can do something like this.

```
import { screen, render } from '@testing-library/vue';

it('should return selected items value', () => {
    render({
        template:`
            <div>
                <your_component :label="'label1'" :value="'value1'"/>                
                <your_component :label="'label2'" :value="'value2'"/>
                <your_component :label="'label3'" :value="'value3'"/>
            </div>
        `,
        components:{ your_component }
    })

    // assuming the label of the component is associated with its input by input's id
    const selectedCheckbox = screen.getByRole('checkbox', { name: 'label1' })
    expect(selectedCheckbox).toBe(...)
})
```